# best way to get a quick printout from C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xps, printdocument

I have a WPF where I've been asked to make allow a user to quickly send a screen shot with a click of a button and the only dialog that should be displayed is a printer dialog.  I have code already written that writes the desired screen shot with a little bit of text out to an XPS file.

So now I'm wondering if for my quick command if I should write this XPS file in the background and save it to a temp location and print it from there, or is there a better way to do this?  It wouldn't be a big deal to re-code this report output using a different method as it is literally only an image with 6 or 7 labels.

Thanks!